# "mount --bind" disappear directory for user

Tags: unix, server, centos, sftp

I have a server setup with multiple sites running with nginx

```
/var/www/site1.com
/var/www/site2.com
```

I want to create chroot users so I created a group and user

```
addgroup sftpgroup
adduser sftpuser1 -G stfpgroup
```

in my sshd_config I updated with:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
   Match Group sftpgroup
   ChrootDirectory /home
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
   X11Forwarding no
   AllowTcpForwarding no
```

I am able to connect sftpuser1 via sftp and see the home directory, Now I want user to have access on site's folder at

```
/var/www/site1.com
```

so I connect sftpuser1 via sftp and created a folder /home/sftpuser1/sit1.com, Than with root login I created mount:

```
mount --bind /var/www/sit1.com /home/sftpuser1/sit1.com
```

Now when I login with sftp of stfpuser1 the folder '/home/sftpuser1/sit1.com' has disappeared
But when I login with root I can see the folder in user's directory and its displaying site1.com's content.

I checked the folder permission were changed to root:root, I chown to sftpuser1:sftpuser1 but still folder doesn't appear.

When I umount folder, its visibile to stfpuser1 again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do so, Here are the steps it took, in sshd_config:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
   Match Group sftpgroup
   ChrootDirectory %h
   ForceCommand internal-sftp
   X11Forwarding no
   AllowTcpForwarding no
```

than I created user with:

```
useradd -g sftpgroup -d /var/www/site1.com site1user
```

At this point I make sure that /var/www/site1.com is owned by root

```
chown root:root /var/www/site1.com
```

than I created another directory where user will be able to write

```
mkdir /var/www/site1.com/http_docs
```

than I changed the permission to user:

```
chown site1user:sftpgroup  /var/www/site1.com/http_docs
```

than I set the user password:

```
passwd site1user
```

and all seems to working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

If the owner of /var/www/ is root and others don't have permission to read from it, then all the directories inside won't be visible to them.

Comment: I changed the owner of /var/www to sftpuser1 and also for /var/www/site1.com, but still its not visible to user.